Drawing simple shapes in raylib c
I can draw text, but I cannot seem to figure out how to draw shapes in raylib c:
Here is my code:
#include "raylib.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Boid {
    int x;
    int y;
    float dir;
    float speed;
};

int main(void)
{
    const int screenWidth = 800;
    const int screenHeight = 450;
    const int numBoids = 50;
    
    struct Boid boidSet[numBoids]; 
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    for(int i=0; i<numBoids; i++)
    {   
        boidSet[i].x = rand() % screenWidth;
        boidSet[i].y = rand() % screenHeight;
        printf("%d, %d\n", boidSet[i].x, boidSet[i].y);
    }
    printf("\n\n\n\n");

    InitWindow(screenWidth, screenHeight, "raylib example window");
    SetTargetFPS(60);

    while (!WindowShouldClose())
    {   
        BeginDrawing();
        ClearBackground(RAYWHITE);
        
        DrawText("window open", 190, 200, 20, BLUE);
        
    DrawTriangle(
            (Vector2){105, 95},
            (Vector2){110, 100},
            (Vector2){105, 110},
            BLACK
        );
    DrawTriangle(
            (Vector2){boidSet[0].x - 10, boidSet[0].y},
            (Vector2){boidSet[0].x + 10, boidSet[0].y},
            (Vector2){boidSet[0].x, boidSet[0].y + 10},
            RED
        );
        for (int i = 0; i < numBoids; i++) {
            DrawTriangle(
                (Vector2){boidSet[i].x - 10, boidSet[i].y},
                (Vector2){boidSet[i].x + 10, boidSet[i].y},
                (Vector2){boidSet[i].x, boidSet[i].y + 10},
                BLACK
            );
        }

        EndDrawing();
    }
    CloseWindow();
    return 0;
    }

The output is the blue text drawn on screen but nothing else, I expect that 50(+2 other simple shapes would get drawn on screen) triangles would get drawn on screen in random places

Known issue. Noted by the source code and, more importantly, by the cheatsheet.
